# PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, dll, import, pyqt, pyqt4

I have 32bit Python (2.7.10) and 32bit PyQt4 installed in my 64bit machine. Every time I would run my program, it throws this error:

...
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui 
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I searched for solutions but they are always pointing at different versions. I already installed 32bit for both Python and PyQt. Still the same error. Any help? Thanks in advance